# Load data Infile statement

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

I have a tab separated text file of the form :

```
62367631    73372
731737373   985985928
62682636    8549594
7478484 70330303
```

let us say chk.txt

This file contains approximately 8 million rows. I need to load this to mysql database based on primary key which is column 1. 
created a table in mysql using this command

1. `CREATE TABLE tid(tweet_id bigint, userid int, PRIMARY KEY (tweet_id));`
2. `LOAD DATA INFILE '\mnt\rt-rp-data\chk.txt' INTO chk FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'`

But I get an error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'chk FIELDS TERMMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'' at line 1
```

How to go about it? I have another question will this be an efficient way of loading around 8 milion rows.

Comment: You are creating a table called `tid` and then loading into a table called `chk`.  That seems unusual.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the keyword `table` and your table name is tid:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '\mnt\rt-rp-data\chk.txt' INTO table tid FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

Comment: done that. but now the error is ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'mona'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: @Saurabh Looks like your user has not the permission or password is wrong.

Comment: how to find the permission rights. As the password is correct since I am able to login to mysql.